# Problem with System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, httprequest

I am stuck in the middle of a problem 
`System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client` for a week. This occurs due to multiline textbox.To solve this I added a property "Validation Request=false" in the header of the page and in web.config page. But it has not worked. Pls help me out.
I want to save `<span></span>` tag with the help of a multiline textbox into a database. It is during that time this prob occurs. Otherwise it works properly.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: it is worked for fckeditor but not work for multiline text box.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following attribute to your httpruntime tag in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

After setting this value, set validateRequest="false" in the pages tag:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you better encode your html before sending it to the database

Use `Server.Encode(YourTextBoxId);`

for example if your command is like :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@htmlcodefromtextbox", TextBox1.Text);
```

try this instead

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@htmlcodefromtextbox",  Server.Encode(YourTextBoxId));
```

and  if your Command is like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@htmlcodefromtextbox", SqlDbType.Text).Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

use this instead

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@htmlcodefromtextbox", SqlDbType.Text ).Value =Server.HtmlEncode( TextBox1.Text);
```

i am Sure this will do finely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add EnableEventValidation="false" either in the page directive of the afflicted page or in the web.config.

It isn't advised however and enabling it means you should take stringent steps to sanitise the input as much as possible.

Regards

Si

Comment: You will open your site to a number of security vulnerabilities by doing so. If you must disable event validation, do so at the page level and not at the site level. Also, you will need to ensure that you sanitize the data coming from the box before displaying it back to the users of your site.